Sci-fi about soldiers, one of which can gender-bend
I once read a description of a story in which the protagonist was in a military/mercenary group. By the end of the story, he was retired, and was visited by his former comrade who can change sex (at will?), becoming female at that point.
Edit: I may have read the description in a Wikipedia page, around 5-10 years ago (before 2019).

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you remember where you found this?  Approximately when was this?  Did you read a review, or someone's post about it?  Do you remember if this was a book or a short story?

Was this one of the (Iain M. Banks) Culture stories? The mercenary Zakalwe has a friend who is a Culture agent. If memory serves she mentions having been male and female.

My first impulse is Joe Haldeman's The Forever War, but I think the twist is actually homosexuality, and then lack of gender, of the human race rather than an individual change.

@Valorum If this is Use of Weapons and gender changing is the most memorable thing this reader has taken from the book, I just...

@DavidW - OP only read a summary, it seems. It's hard to know what emphasis to give certain elements, versus how much it's mentioned in the books. Note that in other books in the same series (Excession, for example) the gender-changing is a huge part of the plot and mentioned dozens of times.

One of David Gerrold's "War Against the Chtorr" novels includes something like this. The protagonist's male friend joins the Telepath Corps. The telepaths in these novels are able to switch bodies with other telepaths. The male friend returns as a female.

Could it possibly be Kaleidoscope Century by John Barnes? The protagonist and his partner, Sadi, are both mercenaries, and Sadi changes from male to female in the course of the story.

That had occurred to me as well. I've found myself thinking about that book off and on over the past decade or so.
